# Updating one table row from another separate table row

Tags: mysql, sql

I am moving 2 rows from a table called `allCooks` to one row in a table called `recipeChallenge` (cookAAA against cookBBB in a pizza challenge)
Each match already has an ID, and this is the row I want to UPDATE

I am doing the update twice, once for cookAAA and then for cookBBB
To update the matchID with cook A...(i-ve left the php variables in)

```
"UPDATE `recipeChallenge` AS v1, 
        `allCooks` AS v2 
    SET v1.`cookAAAID` = v2.`cookID`, 
        v1.`cookAAAName` = v2.`cookName` 
  WHERE     v1.`matchID`='" .$matchID."' 
        AND v2.`cookID`= '" .$cookAID."'";
```

and then for cook B

```
"UPDATE `recipeChallenge` AS v1, 
        `allCooks` AS v2 
    SET v1.`cookBBBID` = v2.`cookID`, 
        v1.`cookBBBName` = v2.`cookName` 
  WHERE     v1.`matchID`='" .$matchID."' 
        AND v2.`cookID`= '" .$cookBID."'";
```

**The table `recipeChallenge` is updating, but the second update is ALSO creating a new `matchID` and row in the `recipeChallenge` table.** Why?

Comment: Provide your table structure. I have a feeling, that this is "whole your approach"

Comment: @Alex, probably the WholeWhole db structure is questionable but lets say i want to do it this way, is the whole approach to THIS problem wrong?

Comment: @Alex,@Prix, Cheers, I'm looking like I have to learn what a JOIN is.

Comment: @Prix, your question uses 1 matching variable, mine has two separate variables that need to be verified separately in the mysql

Comment: @Gamemorize so? just use 2 on it, don't see what is the difficult on it, didn't u say you would go learn/read about JOIN?

Comment: @prix, JOIN is not necessary here, why are you advocating I update a whole table with JOIN when i want to update a row?

Comment: @Gamemorize I am not advocating anything that is the right way to do it. You want to update table A with/using data from table B you can easily achieve that with JOIN and you're the one who said `I have to learn what a JOIN is`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as :

```
"UPDATE `recipeChallenge` AS v1, 
    `allCooks` AS v2 , 
    `allCooks` AS v3 
SET v1.`cookAAAID` = v2.`cookID`, 
    v1.`cookAAAName` = v2.`cookName`,
    v1.`cookBBBID` = v3.`cookID`, 
    v1.`cookBBBName` = v3.`cookName`
WHERE     v1.`matchID`='" .$matchID."' 
    AND v2.`cookID`= '" .$cookAID."'
    AND v3.`cookID`= '" .$cookBID."'";
```

Comment: Thanks! You confirmed that my mysql was fine (now better)!